# clickable padding

Tags: android, ui, imageview

Есть небольшая иконка в ImageView, попадать пальце по которой слегка неудобно. Есть грязный вариант с вкладыванием иконки во Framelayout и лепить listener к layout, но можно ли сделать ImageView с паддингами и сделать так чтобы падинги были кликабельными(казалось бы они должны были быть кликабельными по умолчанию но нет)?

Comment: А вы пробовали? )) У Вас в вопросе есть ответ.

Comment: покажите что вы сделали, в вашем вопросе есть ошибки. А если вы считаете что padding уменьшают размер View это не так, его кликабельный Frame остается прежним. Вывод у вас может быть проблема в верстке

Comment: Да вы правды. Проект собирался из нескольких репозиториев и просто не пересобрал нужный модуль в течении нескольких раз. Вопрос не корректный, все работает